# Probability that two integers are coprime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, asymptotics

Maybe it is a silly question, but anyway. We know that the probability that two positive integers are coprime is $6/\pi^2$. However, for fixed positive integers $r$ and $s$, I'd want to compute the probability of $(a,b)$ such that $ra$ and $sb$ are coprime. By elementary computations, it turns out that$$|\{(a,b):a\le x, b\le x,gcd(ra,sb)=1\}|=\frac{6}{\pi^2}rs\cdot x^2+O(x),$$as $x\rightarrow+\infty$. It doesn't make sense to me if $rs>1$!
My computation:\begin{align*}
\sum_{a\le x,b\le x}\sum_{d|ra,d|sb}\mu(d)&=\sum_{b\le x}\sum_{d\le rx,d|sb}\mu(d)\sum_{a\le x, d|ra}1\\
&=rx\sum_{b\le x}\sum_{d\le rx}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}+O(x)\\
&=rx\sum_{d\le rx}\frac{\mu(d)}{d}\sum_{b\le x,d|sb}1+O(x)\\
&=rsx^2\sum_{d\le rx}\frac{\mu(d)}{d^2}+O(x)\\
&=rsx^2\Big(\frac{6}{\pi^2}+O\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)\Big)+O(x),
\end{align*}here I assume $r\le s$.

Comment: Please edit to include your "elementary computations".  Note that if $\gcd(r,s)>1$ then the answer is clearly $0$.

Comment: You right, so probably there are some mistakes in my computations.

Comment: So...go through it line by line with, way, $(r,s)=(2,2)$ to spot the problem.  In general, the answer has got to depend heavily on $r,s$.  If, say, $r$ is the product of the first billion primes, and $s$ is the product of the second billion primes,  you'll get a very different answer than if $r=1, s=2$, say.

Comment: I still can't see if there are mistakes...by the way, the asymptotic I obtained doesn't make sense right?